# C# and USBHIDDRIVER write() always return false

Tags: c#, usb, libusb

Work with http://www.florian-leitner.de/index.php/2007/08/03/hid-usb-driver-library/

```
`USBHIDDRIVER.USBInterface usbI = new USBInterface("vid_0b6a", "pid_0022");
byte[] startCMD = new byte[8];
startCMD[7] = 4;
usbI.Connect();
usbI.write(startCMD);`
```

"cnnect" return true but "write' always return false, return in this place:

```
 `Result = USBSharp.WriteFile(hidHandle, ref outputReportBuffer[0],
  outputReportBuffer.Length, ref NumberOfBytesWritten, 0);
  Success = (Result == 0) ? false : true;`
```

Comment: Error reporting is very inadequate in that library.  The [DllImport] declarations are missing SetLastError = true, the code is missing Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() calls.  So you just can't find out why it doesn't work.  Throw it away or improve it.